# Enviar post com múltiplos valores através do JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho esse código JQuery para enviar um Post.

```
var formTest = document.createElement('form');
formTest.setAttribute("method", "post");
formTest.setAttribute("action", "");
var post = document.createElement("input");
post.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
post.setAttribute("name", "idsTransf");
post.setAttribute("value", "25");
formTest.appendChild(post); 
document.body.appendChild(formTest);
formTest.submit();
```

Nesse caso, envio um post com o valor do "idsTransf". Como faço pra enviar o post com múltiplos valores, através desse código?

Answer (score 1):

A partir dos dados no form

```
post.id = "submit";
```

Primeiro você vai precisar obter os dados desse form, logo após fazer o append no documento

```
var _url = "caminho/para/o/arquivo.php"
var _data = new FormData($("#submit")[0]);
```

Assim você pode utilizar função ajax a partir do form

```
$.ajax({
        url: _url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: _data,
        timeout: 20000,
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //Código para resposta da requisição
        }, error: function(data){
            //Código para falha na requisição
        });
```

**processData: false e  contentType: false** -> não transforma data em formato Json para FormData, pois já é um FormData

Você também pode passar um array porém deve utilizar o seguinte código

```
$.ajax({
        url: _url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {name1:array(valor1,valor2),name2:array(valor3,valor4)},
        timeout: 20000,
        success: function (data) {
            //Código para resposta da requisição
        }, error: function(data){
            //Código para falha na requisição
        });
```

**processData e contentType** -> na configuração padrão transforma data em formato Json para FormData

No caso não é necessário criar o form